# Transfer data auto from table to other table in phpMyAdmin

Tags: json, phpmyadmin

Transfer *JSON* table data to other table auto. in *phpMyAdmin*.
I want way to transfer table has *JSON* data to other table in *phpmyadmin*

Comment: Elaborate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

From the Operations tab of that table, you can pick to "Copy table to (database.table)" which lets you pick an existing database to copy this particular table to. Sounds like exactly what you're looking for; it will copy the table regardless of the type of data, including your JSON column types.

[image: Copy table dialog]